# How to write a Q with a dot above, for differential notation?

Tags: internationalization

I want to write a Q with a dot above. How can I make it happen? I need it in omni graffle.

[image]

thanks.

Comment: What application are you using

Comment: I thank you for asking this question and @buscar for answering it. I never quite thought of this situation before. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q̇** can be made a part of keyboard input using the replace.

Then when you type your chosen word it will be replaced with the **Q̇**.

Here is a sample: I have chosen to call it qdot *(genius :)*

You can find another **Q̇** on the web and use it (Paste) instead.

[image: qdot]

So now when ever you type "qdot" it will be replaced with your symbol. *(works in most applications)*

Comment: wow, nice solution. never used it. My list is totally empty, but now has Q̇ ... ups, can't write `q d o t` anymore :-)

Comment: +1 from me - I simply *love* the text replace functionality; use it for a myriad things, from my email address to adding key command symbols in SE answers.

Comment: It would appear you can no longer use the word "qdot", without the symbol immediately showing up. There are two solutions to this problem. 1. If you type in the word qdot and it gets replaced with the symbol, you can typically use Command + z on a Mac, or ctrl-z on a PC product, and the symbol will revert to the characters. 2. If you instead use qdot_ for the autocorrect entry, you can type in qdot without Word autocorrecting. When you want the dot over the q, type in qdot_ instead. If you use the underscore following any special characters you create, typing this in becomes pretty automatic.